# Install gentoo on macbook pro

Tags: installation, gentoo

I'd like to install Gentoo on my Macbook Pro, which I bought in early 2011. The model is 7.1.  All I have done was follow the Gentoo Macbook Pro wiki. I used `diskutils` to partition my disk, then I installed `rEFIt`.

When I started the installation from the Live CD, I can't get into Gentoo standard shell. From the message printed out, it seems like the kernel can't find CD-ROM.

So I used a Live DVD. Unfortunately, it could not even boot. I did a lot of research on the Internet, some people suggested USB booting.

So I made a USB boot disk following the Gentoo official guide, however, I got a "boot error." 
I wonder if anybody has succeed in installing Gentoo on Macbook Pro? If possible, tell me the key procedure.

PS:All the images I used were the latest on the Gentoo mirror

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for [su], but it is lacking a _huge_ amount of detail that they would require. Which gentoo live dvd? A recent version? One known to work with Apple's EFI boot process? Or are you using BootCamp? What errors _specifically_ are you getting?

Comment: try to boot with http://www.sysresccd.org/ from CD or USB. it has some advantages over gentoo livecd

Comment: sysresccd is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try [Gentoo Prefix](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/) first?

Comment: yes, now i have installed gentoo prefix on my laptop computer, but lots of packages are masked ...